# Redirect to Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint-server, iis, redirect

I'm trying to configure IIS/SharePoint to redirect to my site collection. I have a site at server.domain.com/sites/collection.

I would like to configure my environment so that when the user types in `https://intranet.domain.com`, they are routed to `server.domain.com/sites/collection`.

I tried setting a default document on the site in IIS, but I get 404s in Internet Explorer and 200s in FireFox for some reason.

The HTTP redirect feature loops, setting the url to server.domain.sites/collection/sites/collection/sites...

How can I accomplish this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect A Web Application to a specific URL (Site Collection URL) via IIS, You should do the following.

- Open IIS.
- In Site Section, Select your web application.
- Below IIS > Click on Http Redirect.

[image]

- Set your redirect URL > Click on Apply

[image]

- In Redirect Behavior, Make sure that you have checked `Only redirect requests to content in this directory`
- No Need to Reset IIS, Go back to browse your source URL it should be navigated directly to the destination URL.

Comment: I set the URL to https://server.domain.com/sites/collection/SitePages/Page.asx, but I'm returned an HTTP Error 404.20 - Not Found. The redirect tried to send me to this address: https://server.domain.com:443/sites/collection/SitePages/Page.aspx/sites/collection/SitePages/Page.aspx/sites/collection/SitePages/Page.aspx/[...] Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: do you tried to browse this URL in your browser?

Comment: do you need to redirect from Http to Https?

Comment: This is all on the same server and the same site in IIS. The URL works when the redirect is not enabled, but trying to hit the SharePoint site collection with the redirect enabled breaks the site. I get the 404.20 error again. The site is entirely in HTTPS, so when https://server.domain.com is entered, I need to route to https://server.domain.com/sites/collection/sitepages/page.aspx, which is on the same server.

Comment: Please check the updated answer, I tried your scenario on my side and working properly, By the way, you are an unregistered user, so please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge and it's preferred to register your account! Also please don't forget to **Mark**  the correct answer as accepted in case it helped and solved your issue to be helpful for future visitors. Thank you for your contribution!